# How to set spinner value from sharedpref?

Tags: android

I am storing the value of spinner like this:

```
mVaccineName=String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
VaccinationModel vaccineModelObject = new VaccinationModel(profileId,mVaccineName,mVaccineDate,
                mVaccinationNotes);
```

If I want to edit the spinner value later, how do I set the spinner according to stored data in sharedpref using model class object like (vaccineModelObject.getmVaccineName)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved my problem like this:

```
String compareValue = profileModelObject.getmGender();
        if (!compareValue.equals(null)) {
            int spinnerPostion = adapter.getPosition(compareValue);
            mGenderSpinner.setSelection(spinnerPostion);
            spinnerPostion = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `setSelection()` function takes the entry's index as its argument, so you'd have to figure out the index value of your string in the adapter array. E.g.:

```
int idx = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < vaccineNames.length; i++) {
    if(vaccineNames[i].equals(vaccineModelObject.getmVaccineName)) {
        idx = i;
        break;
    }
}

spinner.setSelection(idx);
```